# Stop Jetpack Compose pointerInteropFilter from consuming input event

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have a vertical `Column` that has two children:

1. A `Pager` composable (from the [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist)), which displays `Text`.
2. A `Canvas` composable that draws two arcs, and a circle.

They are ordered in the same order described here. I want the `Text` to always render behind the `Canvas`.

---

### Implementation Details

The `Canvas` composable has a `Modifier.pointerInteropFilter` that handles `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. If the event is not within 10% distance of the arc, then it is ignored, and `false` returned.

My understanding was returning `false` would indicate that the event has not been consumed, and therefore would be passed through for the `Pager` to handle - but this is not the case. Once the `Modifier.pointerInteropFilter` has been registered, the `Pager` never receives input events, regardless of returning `true` or `false`.

---

### Layout

Below is a reduced version of my current implementation, for brevity. I have a `Column` that renders the `Pager` first, then the `Canvas`.

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    // The Pager should always be rendered behind the Canvas. This is to
    // prevent the Text from rending on top when being dragged.
    HorizontalPager(
        state = rememberPagerState(pageCount = 8000, initialPage = 4000)
    ) { page ->
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = "25:00",
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontSize = 60.sp
        )
    }
}

var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0.25f) }

ArcSeekBar(progress, false) { change ->
    progress = change
}
```

In this example, I have hardcoded the `pointerInteropFilter` to always return false, under the assumption that it would not consume/block the event, allowing it to pass through to the `Pager`.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ArcSeekBar(progress: Float, interaction: Boolean, changed: (Float) -> Unit) {
    val sweepAngle = 270.0f

    var width: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var height: Int by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .aspectRatio(1.0f)
            .onSizeChanged {
                width = it.width
                height = it.height
            }
            .pointerInteropFilter {
                // Reduced for brevity, but whatever the function returns
                // the Pager composable behind it will never receive input events.
                false
            },
    ) {
        // Omitted for brevity, draw two arcs and a circle
    }
}
```

---

For reference, my layout produces the following:

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code

Comment: @Poliziano Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @HBB20 Not yet. I have worked around it for now by reducing the width of the `HorizontalPager` so that it does not overlap the progress bar area. Looks visually poor when dragging the pager text as it clips.

Answer (score 1):

With Jetpack Compose 1.4.1 and HorizontalPager from `androidx.compose.foundation.pager.HorizontalPager` instead of accompanist one   this is no longer an issue.