# Tracking the finger position in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, once the user places a finger down on a screen and moves it, I want to be notified of the finger position.

How can I track the finger movement?

Answer (score 0):

The mechanism for this is a Composable's Modifier `pointerInput` value.

```
Surface(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                positionX = change.position.x
                positionY = change.position.y
                Log.d("location", "${change.position}")
            }
         }){
    ......
}
```

The `pointerInput` has a variety of the gesture detectors you can specify to detect only certain types of gestures, which is very helpful.   With the code above, I was able to allow the user to drag a circle around the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`Modifier.pointerInput()` offers many options such as detecting tap gestures with long press, double tap, or drag gestures or transform gestures for detecting zoom, rotate, centroid change or pan motions.

However with drag gestures you are not able to detect initial down because it requires a threshold to be passed via for onDragStart to kick in.

You need to check out `awaitFirstDown()` when first pointer is down then `awaitPointerEvent()` in a loop for **move** events and end of loop for **up** event.

You can find my detailed answer about gestures [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64571945/how-can-i-get-ontouchevent-in-jetpack-compose/70847531#70847531) and how to build a basic drawing app using gestures is available in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090111/how-to-draw-on-jetpack-compose-canvas-using-touch-events).

Also parameter or parameters of `Modifier.pointerInput(keys`) are very important to restart closure when you don't want to hold obsolete values.