Remove raised fingers simultaneously
I have a problem, I have a method to control how many fingers I have in a box with Jetpack Compose, this way I update the positions so they are always updated according to where the fingers are, and for each finger, I paint a circle with Canvas.
 when(motionEvent.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
     MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
         MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN - > {
             val updatedPositions =
             mutableMapOf < Int,
             Pair < Float,
             Float >> ()
             for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                 if (i < 5) {
                     val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                     val x = motionEvent.getX(i)
                     val y = motionEvent.getY(i)
                     updatedPositions[id] = Pair(x, y)
                 }
             }
             viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
         }

     MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE - > {
         val updatedPositions =
         mutableMapOf < Int,
         Pair < Float,
         Float >> ()
         for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
             if (i < 5) {
                 val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                 val x = motionEvent.getX(i)
                 val y = motionEvent.getY(i)
                 updatedPositions[id] = Pair(x, y)
             }
         }
         viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
     }

     MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
         MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP - > {
             val updatedPositions = state.touchedPositions.toMutableMap()
             for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                 val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                 updatedPositions.remove(id)
             }

             viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
             viewModel.setTimeRemaining(value = 0)
         }
 }

The problem I have is in the ACTION_UP event, and it is that if I have two fingers and I lift them at exactly the same time, the event is only triggered once, so it still leaves a painted circle on the screen.
onDraw = {
    if (state.isUserSelected.not() && state.touchedPositions.isNotEmpty()) {
        state.touchedPositions.forEach {
            (id, position) - >
            drawCircle(
                color = getColorForId(id),
                radius = 40. dp.toPx(),
                center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
            )
        }

    } else {
        state.touchedPositions.forEach {
            (_, position) - >
            drawCircle(
                color = DarkPink,
                radius = size.toPx(),
                center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
            )
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.White,
                radius = 40. dp.toPx(),
                center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
            )
        }
    }
}

I update with all the code where you can see where I get the motionEvent from.
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .weight(1 f)
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16. dp))
    .background(SoftPeach)
) {

    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInteropFilter {
            motionEvent - >
                if (state.isUserSelected.not()) {
                    when(motionEvent.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN - > {
                                val updatedPositions =
                                mutableMapOf < Int,
                                Pair < Float,
                                Float >> ()
                                for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                                    if (i < 5) {
                                        val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                                        val x = motionEvent.getX(i)
                                        val y = motionEvent.getY(i)
                                        updatedPositions[id] = Pair(x, y)
                                    }
                                }
                                viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
                            }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE - > {
                            val updatedPositions =
                            mutableMapOf < Int,
                            Pair < Float,
                            Float >> ()
                            for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                                if (i < 5) {
                                    val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                                    val x = motionEvent.getX(i)
                                    val y = motionEvent.getY(i)
                                    updatedPositions[id] = Pair(x, y)
                                }
                            }
                            viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
                        }

                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP - > {
                                val updatedPositions = state.touchedPositions.toMutableMap()
                                for (i in 0 until motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                                    val id = motionEvent.getPointerId(i)
                                    updatedPositions.remove(id)
                                }

                                viewModel.updateTouchedPositions(updatedPositions)
                                viewModel.setTimeRemaining(value = 0)
                            }
                    }
                    true

                } else {
                    false
                }
        },
        onDraw = {
            if (state.isUserSelected.not() && state.touchedPositions.isNotEmpty()) {
                state.touchedPositions.forEach {
                    (id, position) - >
                    drawCircle(
                        color = getColorForId(id),
                        radius = 40. dp.toPx(),
                        center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                    )
                }

            } else {
                state.touchedPositions.forEach {
                    (_, position) - >
                    drawCircle(
                        color = DarkPink,
                        radius = size.toPx(),
                        center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                    )
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.White,
                        radius = 40. dp.toPx(),
                        center = Offset(position.first, position.second)
                    )
                }
            }
        })
}


Can you update your question to also show how you retrieve motionEvent?

Also, do you do interop with views?

@Leviathan There I have updated the code where you can see what I do and where I get the motionEvent from.

Regarding my second, comment: Since you use pointerInteropFilter instead of pointerInput, I assume you really do need the interoperability with the old view system? Or would it be possible to switch to pointerInput, as it is should be done when you just use Compose? Can you be more specific on why?

@Leviathan No, I don't use the old view system, as my application is completely made in Jetpack Compose, but I have never done something similar and it was the first thing I found, can I get the same result with pointerInput?

Of course, that's what it's for. You can refactor your code to use pointerInput (which works quite differently, though), and update your question with the new code if you still experience a problem.

You can refer this answer for using Modifier.pointerInput with canvas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090111/how-to-draw-on-jetpack-compose-canvas-using-touch-events/71090112#71090112. And to get not only primary pointerEvent but all of them you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955466/jetpack-compose-intercept-pinch-zoom-in-child-layout

You can use Modifier in second link to get current PointerInputChanges and define your logic inside onGesture and other gesture callbacks
